# bash script - checking multiple worker processes

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check multiple processes (have similar name) running or not, using this bash script. Processes names follwo a particular convention worker1.gs where X is a serial number have value 1 to 4. I have a snippet there for checking worker 1 and 2 and so on... but I want to save the value in array [1,2,3.4] and loop through it to check it ..how to do that? Also below script terminate after checking first process..how to fix that as well?

```
  #!/bin/bash

  pidof /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker1.gs >/dev/null
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Restarting Worker1: $(date)" >> /var/log/httpd/watchdog.txt
    /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker1.gs
  fi

  pidof /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker2.gs >/dev/null
  if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Restarting Worker2: $(date)" >> /var/log/httpd/watchdog.txt
    /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker2.gs
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make loops like in C:

```
for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo "$i" ; done
```

and you can streamline

```
pidof /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker1.gs >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then ... fi
```

into

```
pidof /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker1.gs >/dev/null || { ... }
```

Combined:

```
for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do
  pidof /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker1.gs >/dev/null || {
     echo "Restarting Worker$i: $(date)" >> /var/log/httpd/watchdog.txt
     /usr/bin/gsx /var/app/transcoding/worker$i.gs
  }   
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `if ! pidof ...` and `$i` (instead of `$1`) ?

Comment: No and "of course!". Thanks for the correction regarding the variable! (As for the conditional, the shell has boolean logic upside down. 0 status means true and nonzero statuses mean false)

Comment: Sure, I know about returning codes. But the question is about running a command in case another one fails, right? `if pidof ...` will run the latter if the former pass (will start the worker if he exists)

Comment: Something like: `if ! $( exit 1 ); then echo 'restarting'; fi`

Comment: @Felipe Arenales It's 5 A.M. here. I think it's time to go to sleep. :D Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: haha bash can be really tricky sometimes. Have a great night, @PSkocik :)

Comment: PSkocick thanks for your answer, but this only starts 9th worker and doens't do anything to all 1 to 8th worker processes